# Move Geowebcache folder to EFS storage

Tags: boundless-suite, geowebcache

I am using Boundless Server 1.0.2(2.12-server-1.0.2) on Cent OS 7

My Geowebcache is located in following directory & My data directory located in EFS storage

**/var/opt/boundless/server/geoserver/tilecache**

I want to move tilecache folder into EFS storage & edited web.xml file as per [this link](https://docs.boundlessgeo.com/suite/1.2.0/geoserver/geowebcache/config.html) then restarted tomcat server but it unable to move its EFS storage

-Clustering is used for this Geoserver

-Tried to edit 'geowebcache.xml' file but unable to update its storage

-Tried same on another standalone Geoserver in my PC (on windows platform),it works perfectly

-Wondering why its not working for Boundless Geoserver.

-Researching on Web

[image]

Comment: Since Boundless no longer exist I would switch to a modern version of GeoServer/GeoWebCache and try again

Comment: @IanTurton : agreed

Comment: @IanTurton :Please mark this as answer.                                                           On Standalone Geo server it works fine. Migrated to Standard Geo server & it resolves my issue. Unfortunately Boundless support does not exit,its better to switch on to stand alone Geo